# How can I find out the longest entry in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, word-count

I asked over at the English Stack Exchange, ["What is the English word with the longest single definition?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358532/which-word-has-the-longest-dictionary-definition) The best answer they could give is that I would need a program that could figure out the longest entry in a (text) file listing dictionary definitions, by counting the amount of characters or words in a given entry, and then provide a list of the longest entries.

I managed to find a dictionary file which converted to text has the following format:

> > a /a/ indefinite article (an before a vowel) 1 any, some, one (have a cookie). 2 one single thing (there’s not a store for miles). 3 per, for each (take this twice a day).
> >
> > aardvark /ard-vark/ n an African mammal with a long snout that feeds on ants.
> >
> > abacus /a-ba-kus, a-ba-kus/ n a counting frame with beads.

As you can see, each definition comes after the pronunciation (enclosed by slashes), and then either:

1) ends with a period, or

2) ends before an example (enclosed by parenthesis), or

3) follows a number and ends with a period or before an example, when a word has multiple definitions.

What I would need, then, is a function or program that can distinguish each definition (including considering multiple definitions of a single word as separate ones), then count the amount of characters and/or words within (ignoring the examples in parenthesis since that is not the proper definition), and finally provide a list of the longest definitions (I don't think I would need more than say, a top 20 or so to compare). If the file format was an issue, I can convert the file to PDF, EPUB, etc. with no problem. And, I guess ideally I would want to be able to choose between counting length by characters and by words, if it was possible.

How should I go to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could import the list into Excel, remove duplicates, use the LEN function to count the number of characters, and then sort by the column with the LEN function.

Comment: It's very easy with a `bash` script in Linux.

Comment: I am on Windows 7. How would Excel differentiate multiple definitions if they're not separated by a line break?